# Excel: How to create a weekly calendar with a drop-down day selection?

Tags: excel, list, drop-down-menu, calendar

I'm trying to create a weekly calendar showing times of availability for a team.  Header is "Monday"/"Tuesday"/"Wednesday" etc., with the time of day and availability of each team member to meet, as shown in the image:

[image: What the calendar should look like]

In the header containing the day of the week, I want to create a drop down box where I can select other days and have the calendar automatically change to that day's availability.  E.g. if I select "Wednesday" from the drop down box, the calendar updates the cells showing the data for Wednesday, but the calendar format still remains. I'm not sure how to do this using Data Validation; I know that Data Validation can create a drop-down list of values, but I don't know how to link the selection from that list to a group of cells that change based on the list selection.

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming that somewhere else there is a repository of information showing a persons availability or not.  Based on your image, in each cell you would need a formula that would go look at the repository of information , and look at the appropriate column based on the value you picked in from your data validation list.  Its the formulas in each cell that are going to do the bulk of your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to accomplish this, but this is my favorite.

[image: Create List]

Create your list, as in the image, cells `E2` to `E8`.

[image: Data Validations selection]

Click Data Validation under Data, Data Tools.  Select `List` in the `Allow:` window and select your range in the `Source:` window. I did this for cell `A2` in the example.

[image: Result]

When done you can select the cell and see the values you can select from.

I recommend that the list be on another sheet and you can make it a table, but basically that is it.

As @Forward Ed pointed out, you still need the formulas in every cell referring to this value and whatever your data fields are in the background.  Probably need `INDEX`/`MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`.

OBTW, you can also type in the values like this:

[image: Data Validations list]